# org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat NOT INSIDE FLINK JARS

Tags: jdbc, apache-flink

- I have created a new Java project in
  eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64.
- I have included the Jars in
  flink-0.8.1\lib.
- I have created the standard WordCount and it works.
- I have modified my WordCount to take input from text files and csv files and it works.
- all the imports work perfectly.
- then i tried *import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.jdbc.JDBCInputFormat*.
- Eclipse doesn't find it?

Why does Eclipse not find the import?

Because inside the jar *flink-java-0.8.1.jar* there is no directory io/jdbc.

I tried the same thing with *flink-0.9.0-bin-hadoop27* and in the jar *flink-dist-0.9.0.jar* there is no *org/apache/flink/api/java/io/jdbc* directory. I uncompressed the jar and searched for the string "jdbcinputformat" with 0 results. I searched the string "jdbc" and it is only mentioned in *org/apache/log4j*, *org/eclipse/jetty*, and in other places that are not *org.apache.flink.api.java.io*

**So my question is: Where do I find the class *JDBCInputFormat*?**

What can I do to access SqlServer2012 in Flink (apart from accessing it outside Flink, create csv files, and then reading them in Flink (It sounds horrible to me since there should be a class specific for that))?

Comment: the `flink-jdbc` project is not contained inside the regular Flink distribution.
But you can easily download the jar file for your flink version (say 0.9.0) from maven central.
In general, I would recommend to use maven for your dependency management. Flink has a quickstart.sh script that generates a ready to use maven file structure for you. Eclipse works quite well with maven projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding module is not included. In order to use it, you need to build Flink from scratch. Run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/flink.git
cd flink
mvn -DskipTests clean install
```

This builds the latest snapshot for flink-0.10-SNAPSHOT. If you want to use stable version 0.9 run different git clone command:

```
git clone -b release-0.9 https://github.com/apache/flink.git
```

In your current project, you need to change the used Flink version in your pom file accordingly, eg, 0.10-SNAPSHOT or 0.9-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: You don't have to build Flink yourself for that. For example "flink-jdbc" is here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.flink%22%20AND%20a%3A%22flink-jdbc%22 (just click on "jar" for your version)